# Custom slider using Vue JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm developing a slider on my Vue project. Now, on page load, the slider is not working means I can only see the dot, not the slider but when I click on the **dot** then it's working can see the slider.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<div class="slideshow-container fade">
    <div class="reservationSlider fade" v-for="(consultation, index) in consultations" :key="index">
        <ReservationItem  v-if="Object.keys(consultations).length" :consultation="consultation"
                    :is_active="consultationIsActive()"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

**And the JS code:**

```
export default {
    components: {
        Notice,
        ConsultationBox,
        Pagination,
        ReservationItem,
        AdvisorItem
    },
    layout: "sidebar",
    mounted() {
        this.handleAutomaticeButtonEnable();
        this.currentSlide(this.slideIndex);
    },
    data() {
        return {
            activePage: 1,
            consultations: {...this.getConsultations} || {},
            slideIndex: 0,
            sliderTimer: '',
        };
    },
    methods: {
        plusSlides(n) {
            return this.showSlides(this.slideIndex += n);
        },
        currentSlide(n) {
            if (this.sliderTimer) {
                window.clearTimeout(this.sliderTimer);
            }
            this.showSlides(this.slideIndex = n);
        },
        showSlides(n) {
            var i; 
            var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("reservationSlider");  
            var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
            console.log(slides.length);
            console.log(slides);    
            if( slides.length ) {
                if (n > slides.length) {
                    this.slideIndex = 1;
                }
                if (n < 1) {
                    this.slideIndex = slides.length;
                }
                for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) { 
                    slides[i].style.display = "none";  
                }
                if(!n) {
                    this.slideIndex++;  
                }
                if (this.slideIndex > slides.length){ 
                    this.slideIndex = 1; 
                }
                console.log(this.slideIndex);
                for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) { 
                    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", ""); 
                }
                if(slides[this.slideIndex - 1]) {
                    slides[this.slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
                } 
                if( dots[this.slideIndex - 1] ) {
                     dots[this.slideIndex - 1].className += " active"; 
                }
                this.sliderTimer = setTimeout(this.showSlides, 3000); 
            }
        },
    },
    
    more code ..... 
}
```

Comment: I think you have a problem using slides.length as an index of a slide. in the showSlide method you have: if (n < 1) {
                    this.slideIndex = slides.length;
                }, because index starts from 0, so the length of [a, b, c] is 3, but the last item index is 2, because a has index 0, b has 1, and c has 2. so to get the last item it should be length -1

Comment: @HassanAliSalem let me try it

Comment: @HassanAliSalem sitll not working. Can you show me full code?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/24rEQ4

Comment: Can you check again? https://codeshare.io/24rEQ4

Comment: @HassanAliSalem sure, I am checking

Comment: still same. I can see only the dot

Comment: I think we need to know some log output, and can you try to utilize class binding? that will make your life much easier: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: I don't understand. What log out I need to show?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224552/discussion-between-hassan-ali-salem-and-shibbir).

Comment: Lots of thanks @HassanAliSalem. You are soooooo helpful. Smackover users should know about it !!!!